# How can I let div inside bootstrap colum scrollable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

As this link : https://jsbin.com/tudeseqomi/edit?html,css,output
the panel width and height shoule be 800px and 450px.
So I want to let the part:

```
<div class="panelFrame">
    <div class="panel">
    </div>
  </div>
```

can scroll because it's too big over the blue zone ,

How can I do this ?

p.s. I don't know why the `<div class="panelFrame">` part become whit on jsbin, on my local it's green

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `overflow-x: scroll;` on  .rightpart class

```
 .rightpart{
      background-color:blue;
      height:500px;
      overflow-x: scroll;
    }
```

See below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set `overflow:hidden/scroll` in css for the green div

Answer (score 0):

You have given the color green to  which is overwritten by the class .panel in one of the included CSS from the following link, https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/panels.less.

Use the property overflow:scroll to have scroll on the element or reduce the width of the 'panelFrame' and use the above property.